# XSLT: how can one match nodes with a specific text()-value/pattern?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to create me a list of specific dependencies of our multi-module Maven project (the end-goal will be to automatically generate a dependency graph of all modules (using PictureUML aka PUML) but I am not quite there, yet).

I am using an XSLT-processor (Saxon 11-4J) to process each module's pom.xml-file and emit its dependencies (i.e. extracting the text portion of the artifactId of pom-snippets like:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>someId-here</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-abc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>someId-here</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-def</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>otherId-here</groupId>
      <artifactId>bar-ghi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

That works using the following XSL-snippet:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pom="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent ="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- overriding XSLT's built-in template which copies all text to the output: -->
    <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="pom:project/pom:dependencies/pom:dependency/pom:artifactId">
<xsl:for-each select=".">depends on: <xsl:value-of select="text()" /><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the above emits ALL dependencies' artifactId listed in the pom.xml and I am only interested here in dependencies referring *to our own modules* (which luckily all have a common prefix like shown in the example). How can one phrase an XSLT-condition to match only nodes *whose text-value* has a specific prefix?

```
<xsl:template match="pom:project/pom:dependencies/pom:dependency/pom:artifactId[???]">
...
```

I.e. what would need to go into the match-condition (denoted above by `[???]`) to only match entries whose test-value starts with, say, "foo-..."? I had tried something like:

```
<xsl:template match="pom:project/pom:dependencies/pom:dependency/pom:artifactId[text()='foo-*']">
```

but that did not work and I while I googled for quite a while I couldn't find any good description or example for such a condition on a text's node. Any XSLT guru out there?

Hope I could make myself clear...

Comment: "I googled for quite a while". I wonder if you ought to adopt a different learning strategy? For example, if you went to the XPath functions documentation at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/, a quick glance at section 5, "functions on strings", would surely lead you straight to the answer. It would certainly be more efficient than trial-and-error guesses.

Comment: @GSerg: Excellent - yes that answered my question.

Comment: @Michael Kay I obviously googled for XSLT descriptions and examples, not XPath. My bad...